# css hover visibility out div

Tags: css

I have one problem about visibility. I have to create this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ztzj2pxm/2/)** from fiddle.

If you click my demo you can see there is a one image. When you hoverover mouse this image then bubble will open. But if you come with the mouse to the left of the image blank bubble opens again. How can I fix this problem ?

```
.balon 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 345px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: #d8dbdf solid 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
    -moz-box-shadow:    -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
    box-shadow:         -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
    visiblility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left: -345px;
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ;
    -o-transition: all .3s ;
    transition: all .3s ;
}

.balon:after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    right: -10px;
    top: 16px;  
}

.vizyon_bg:hover .balon
{
    opacity:1; 
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:5; 
    transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s linear .5s;
}
```

Comment: works fine in fiddle. i can't see any blank thing :(

Comment: Dude you wrote hover effect for `div .vizyon_bg_img` which cover the image that is the reason it came.

Comment: You have a misspelling in your css in `.balon`: `visiblility` should be `visibility`

Comment: @lolka_bolka oh my god I have escaped attention. Thanks for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude i found the solution! just replace your balon's CSS and you're done! you have wrong z-index :}

I've created JSFiddle for you! http://jsfiddle.net/9pgqc24c/

```
.balon 
{
position: absolute;
width: 345px;
z-index:-99999;
height: auto;
padding: 3px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
border: #d8dbdf solid 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
-moz-box-shadow:    -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
box-shadow:         -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
  visiblility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  margin-left:-345px;
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ;
        -o-transition: all .3s ;
        transition: all .3s ;
}
```